# Cannot Parse Soap Response

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

for starter, im learning to make a call to Soap webservices using SoapClient in php. i found myself stuck in getting value in very complicated xml soap response that i need to extract the value from it. i also refer to some of the method in this forum but didnt understand. below are the response that ive recieved:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:CleanseUnicodeResponse xmlns:ns="http://soap.web.tsi.trillium.com">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:TrilliumRecord" xmlns:ax21="http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax21:numberFields>4</ax21:numberFields>
            <ax21:trilliumFieldValues xsi:type="ax21:TrilliumFieldValue">
               <ax21:trilliumField>CLEANSE_NAME</ax21:trilliumField>
               <ax21:trilliumValue>Fiery Ass</ax21:trilliumValue>
            </ax21:trilliumFieldValues>
            <ax21:trilliumFieldValues xsi:type="ax21:TrilliumFieldValue">
               <ax21:trilliumField>CLEANSE_ID</ax21:trilliumField>
               <ax21:trilliumValue>880909999999</ax21:trilliumValue>
            </ax21:trilliumFieldValues>
            <ax21:trilliumFieldValues xsi:type="ax21:TrilliumFieldValue">
               <ax21:trilliumField>CLEANSE_GENDER</ax21:trilliumField>
               <ax21:trilliumValue>M</ax21:trilliumValue>
            </ax21:trilliumFieldValues>
            <ax21:trilliumFieldValues xsi:type="ax21:TrilliumFieldValue">
               <ax21:trilliumField>CLEANSE_DOB</ax21:trilliumField>
               <ax21:trilliumValue>090988</ax21:trilliumValue>
            </ax21:trilliumFieldValues>
            <ax21:userKey xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:CleanseUnicodeResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and here the code that i developed to retrieved the value. i cant seem to dump it properly to array. it keep getting null or empty body.

```
try{

    $name = "fiery ass";
    $ic = "880909-99-9999";
    $gender = "male";
    $dob = "12122019";
    $webkey = 'U4GBXJZ5';

    $url = 'http://192.168.4.147:8484/TrilliumSOAP/services/TrilliumSOAP?wsdl'; 

    $soapclient = new SoapClient(null, array(
                        'location' => $url,
                        'uri'      => $url,
                        'trace'    => 1,
                        ));


    $xml_post_string = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
              <s:Header>
                <Action s:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:CleanseUnicode</Action>
              </s:Header>
              <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <CleanseUnicode xmlns="http://soap.web.tsi.trillium.com">
                  <webKey>' . $webkey . '</webKey>
                  <projectName>TSS DEMO</projectName>
                  <inputRecord>
                    <trilliumFieldValues xmlns="http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd">
                      <trilliumField>SHAREHOLDER_NAME</trilliumField>
                      <trilliumValue>' . $name . '</trilliumValue>
                    </trilliumFieldValues>
                    <trilliumFieldValues xmlns="http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd">
                      <trilliumField>SHAREHOLDER_ID</trilliumField>
                      <trilliumValue>' . $ic . '</trilliumValue>
                    </trilliumFieldValues>
                    <trilliumFieldValues xmlns="http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd">
                      <trilliumField>GENDER</trilliumField>
                      <trilliumValue>' . $gender . '</trilliumValue>
                    </trilliumFieldValues>
                    <trilliumFieldValues xmlns="http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd">
                      <trilliumField>DOB</trilliumField>
                      <trilliumValue>' . $dob . '</trilliumValue>
                    </trilliumFieldValues>
                    <userKey xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd" />
                  </inputRecord>
                  <outputFields>CLEANSE_NAME</outputFields>
                  <outputFields>CLEANSE_ID</outputFields>
                  <outputFields>CLEANSE_GENDER</outputFields>
                  <outputFields>CLEANSE_DOB</outputFields>
                </CleanseUnicode>
              </s:Body>
            </s:Envelope>'; 



    $response = $soapclient->__doRequest($xml_post_string,$url,$url,0); 

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'http://soap.web.tsi.trillium.com');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('xml', 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace');
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ax21', 'http://quality.tsi.trillium.com/xsd');

    $xpath = '/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:CleanseUnicodeResponse/text()';

    $result = $xml->xpath($xpath);

    var_dump($result);


}catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

am i parsing it wrongly? or i miss something? i really lost here.

Comment: You may try json format, it is very easy to serialize and deserialise back to php.

Comment: @KennethKorir i done that using json encoding and decoding. still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$url = 'http://192.168.4.147:8484/TrilliumSOAP/services/TrilliumSOAP?wsdl'; 
$trace = true;
$exceptions = true;
$token = 9999999;
$soap_version='SOAP_1_2';
$connection_timeout=180;
$name = "fiery ass";



$params=array( 

     "ic"= >"880909-99-9999",
    "gender" = >"male",
    "dob" => "12122019",
    "webkey "=> 'U4GBXJZ5'
);

try
        {

$client = new SoapClient($url, array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,'soap_version'=>$soap_version,  'trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions,'connection_timeout'=>$connection_timeout));
           $response = $client->TrilliumRecord($params);

            $feedback= $response->TrilliumRecordResult; 

              // var_dump($feedback);  

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            //catch an error

        }


}
```

Comment: I assume you have enable soap client in your php

Comment: Uncomment // var_dump($feedback);  to see reponspe